# Cannot resolve symbol 'Notification'

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have the following method to create a notification in a brand new android studio project in the MainActivity.java:

```
public void getNot(View v){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
}
```

But it gets a "Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationManager'" error and similar ones for any other notification related objects. Why does this not work? It's a brand new project.

Comment: Are you imported necessary packages?

Comment: @user7790438 Normally Android Studio will prompt the user if it's missing an import and it hasn't done this. Do you know which classes need to be imported?

Comment: Just press Alt+Enter and you will see the suggestions.

Comment: @user7790438 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put the cursor inside the "NotificationManager" then press Alt+Enter then select import class/package